# Struggling to optimize rails WHERE NOT IN query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

Here's the query as it is in rails:

```
User.limit(20).
  where.not(id: to_skip, number_of_photos: 0).
  where(age: @user.seeking_age_min..@user.seeking_age_max).
  tagged_with(@user.seeking_traits, on: :trait, any: true).
  tagged_with(@user.seeking_gender, on: :trait, any: true).ids
```

And here's the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Note the `id <> ALL(...)` part is shortened. There are around 10K ids in it.

```
Limit  (cost=23.32..5331.16 rows=20 width=1698) (actual time=2237.871..2243.709 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=23.32..875817.48 rows=3300 width=1698) (actual time=2237.870..2243.701 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=22.89..857813.95 rows=8311 width=1702) (actual time=463.757..2220.691 rows=1351 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (users.id = users_trait_taggings_356a192.taggable_id)
              ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.29..834951.51 rows=37655 width=1698) (actual time=455.122..2199.322 rows=7866 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                    Filter: ((number_of_photos <> 0) AND (age >= 18) AND (age <= 99) AND (id <> ALL ('{7066,7065,...,15624,23254}'::integer[])))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 7652
              ->  Index Only Scan using taggings_idx on taggings users_trait_taggings_356a192  (cost=0.42..22767.59 rows=11393 width=4) (actual time=0.048..16.009 rows=4554 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((tag_id = 2) AND (taggable_type = 'User'::text) AND (context = 'trait'::text))
                    Heap Fetches: 4554
        ->  Index Scan using index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context on taggings users_trait_taggings_5df4b2a  (cost=0.42..2.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1351)
              Index Cond: ((taggable_id = users.id) AND ((taggable_type)::text = 'User'::text) AND ((context)::text = 'trait'::text))
              Filter: (tag_id = ANY ('{4,6}'::integer[]))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Total runtime: 2243.913 ms
```

[Complete version here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/3UG).

It seems like there's something wrong with `Index Scan using users_pkey on users` where the index scan is taking a very long time. Even though there's an index on `age`, `number_of_photos` and the `id`:

```
add_index "users", ["age"], name: "index_users_on_age", using: :btree
add_index "users", ["number_of_photos"], name: "index_users_on_number_of_photos", using: :btree
```

`to_skip` is an array of user ids to not skip. A `user` has many `skips`. Each `skip` has a `partner_id`.

So to fetch `to_skip` I'm doing:

```
to_skip = @user.skips.pluck(:partner_id)
```

I tried to isolate the query to just:

```
sql = User.limit(20).
  where.not(id: to_skip, number_of_photos: 0).
  where(age: @user.seeking_age_min..@user.seeking_age_max).to_sql
```

And still getting the same problem with the explain analyze. Again, list of user ids is snipped:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..435.34 rows=20 width=1698) (actual time=0.219..4.844 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..819629.38 rows=37655 width=1698) (actual time=0.217..4.838 rows=20 loops=1)
        Filter: ((id IS NOT NULL) AND (number_of_photos <> 0) AND (age >= 18) AND (age <= 99) AND (id <> ALL ('{7066,7065,...,15624,23254}'::integer[])))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 6
Total runtime: 5.044 ms
```

[Complete version here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/jux).

Any thoughts on how I can optimize this query in rails + postgres?

**EDIT: Here are the relevant models:**

[**User model**](https://gist.github.com/vu0tran/9c9cca45966246306b7adef41408c93f)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_messageable required: :body, # default [:topic, :body]
                      dependent: :destroy

  has_many :skips, :dependent => :destroy

  acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :seeking_gender, :trait, :seeking_race
  scope :by_updated_date, -> {
    order("updated_at DESC")
  }
end

# schema

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email", default: "", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.text     "skips", array: true
  t.integer  "number_of_photos", default: 0
  t.integer  "age"
end

add_index "users", ["age"], name: "index_users_on_age", using: :btree
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["number_of_photos"], name: "index_users_on_number_of_photos", using: :btree
add_index "users", ["updated_at"], name: "index_users_on_updated_at", order: {"updated_at"=>:desc}, using: :btree
```

[**Skips model**](https://gist.github.com/vu0tran/d506c04ec7790fc60359e19d08953cf3)

```
class Skip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# schema

create_table "skips", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "partner_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "skips", ["partner_id"], name: "index_skips_on_partner_id", using: :btree
add_index "skips", ["user_id"], name: "index_skips_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Please post the code of all relevant models.

Comment: Added them. Please let me know if they are sufficient.

Comment: You have a dedicated `Skip` model and also `Users.skips` array field. What is the reason for the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed issue is likely due to the long list of ids in `to_skip` (about 60Kb) getting passed in as array. The solution then would be to rework it to be a result of a subquery so postgress could better optimize the query.

When building `to_skip`, try using `select` instead of `pluck`. `pluck` returns an array which you then pass to main query. `select`, in turn, returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`, the sql of which can be included with the main query, potentially making it more efficient.

```
to_skip = @user.skips.select(:partner_id)
```

Until your models code is posted it's hard to make more specific suggestions. The general direction I'd explore would be to try and merge all the relevant steps into a single query to let the database do the optimizations.

**UPDATE**

The Active Record query using `select` would look something like this (I skipped `taggable` stuff as it seemingly does not affect the performance much):

```
User.limit(20).
  where.not(id: @user.skips.select(:partner_id), number_of_photos: 0).
  where(age: 0..25)
```

This is the SQL query that gets executed. Note how ids to skip are fetched by a subquery:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"
  WHERE ("users"."number_of_photos" != 0)
    AND ("users"."id" NOT IN (
      SELECT "skips"."partner_id"
        FROM "skips"
        WHERE "skips"."user_id" = 1
    ))
    AND ("users"."age" BETWEEN 0 AND 25)
  LIMIT 20
```

Try running your query this way and see how it affects the performance.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try. In the mean time I have also added the model annotation + schema

Comment: Actually, how do write the query now with the select(:partner_id)?

to_skip = @user.skips.select(:partner_id)
results = User.limit(20).where.not(id: to_skip).ids

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: I copy and pasted the exact query and received 0 results. This was the "to_sql" of the query:


SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."number_of_photos" != 0) AND ("users"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "skips"."partner_id" FROM "skips" WHERE "skips"."user_id" = 23254)) AND ("users"."age" BETWEEN 0 AND 25) LIMIT 20


When I change the query to use PLUCK instead, User.limit(20).
      where.not(id: @user.skips.pluck(:partner_id), number_of_photos: 0).
      where(age: 0..25) 

It works as expected and returns 20 items.

Comment: It seems like the rails "where.not" isn't working correctly. When I change the query to use only "where" it works and returns the skipped objects as expected. But when I use a "where.not" it does not return all the users that are not in the set.

Comment: What SQL are you getting when using `pluck`?

Comment: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

Comment: And here's the working non "NOT" query:

SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "skips"."partner_id" FROM "skips" WHERE "skips"."user_id" = 27254)

Comment: There is no semantical difference between your `pluck` query and the subselect. Try reducing the main query to absolute minimum and make sure the subquery returns correct values comparing with the `pluck` results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118730/discussion-between-vu-tran-and-nic-nilov).